# make error: /bin/sh: -C: command not found

Tags: cmake

Running the following:

```
~ % cd faust
faust % make
```

returns this:

```
if test -d .git; then git submodule update --init --recursive; fi
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make -C build cmake BACKENDS=regular.cmake TARGETS=regular.cmake
cd faustdir &&  -C ../backends/regular.cmake -C ../targets/regular.cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release "-DWORKLET=off" -DLIBSDIR=lib -G 'Unix Makefiles' ..
/bin/sh: -C: command not found
make[1]: *** [cmake] Error 127
make: *** [compiler] Error 2
```

And I have no clue how to fix these errors... Nothing I tried worked. Any ideas?

Comment: Probably, something wrong is with your code. Without viewing that code we cannot help you. Please, (re-)read [ask] and edit your question post accordingly.

Comment: I guess it should be `cd faustdir && cmake -C ...` but smth went wrong (looks like cmake wasn't detected properly and a shell variable expanded into an empty string).